# YII2 error - The "id" configuration for the Application is required

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to start with YII2 (I should say that quite difficult after ASP.NET MVC) and got this error, but can't get what's wrong - id property has been set.

```
<?php
return [
    'id' => 'crmapp',
    'basePath' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../'),
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'somekey'
        ],
        'urlManager'=>[
            'enablePrettyUrl'=>true,
            'showScriptName'=>false
        ]
    ],
    'db'=> [
        require(__DIR__.'/db.php'),
    ]];
```

Here is full error text:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The "id" configuration for the Application is required.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\crmapp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php:220 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\crmapp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(202): yii\base\Application->preInit('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\crmapp\web\index.php(10): yii\base\Application->__construct('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\crmapp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php on line 220
```

Here is web/index.php

```
<?php
require(__DIR__.'/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
$config = (__DIR__.'/../config/web.php');
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Comment: what is the error exactly?

Comment: show `web/index.php`.

Comment: That's whole web.php already.

Comment: show `web/index.php` not `web.php`.

Comment: @IncognitoSkulll, please see update.

Comment: All of the files and folders was created manually, that's not template created by composer, so this could be an issue.

Comment: Well that's your answer, create a basic app with composer, if it works then you did it wrong, if it doesn't work then it's your computer, just compare the two config files!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
$config = (__DIR__.'/../config/web.php');
```

`$config` contains the path to `web.php`, not its contents. It should be:

```
$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');
```